# Dax to calculate KPI Score based on numeric and non-numeric values

Tags: powerbi, dax

[Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QITYg.png)

Please can someone help me in writing a dax, where i can take both numeric and non-numeric values

wrote below Dax but error on text values

```
P_score = 'Input - PI Scoring'[Score 2]/'Input - PI Scoring'[Score 1]
```

Comment: and what you want to do with text? You want it to detect text, and print something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should make it fail-safe! Same logic in Excel: IFERROR is your function:

```
P_score = IFERROR(
    'Input - PI Scoring'[Score 2]/'Input - PI Scoring'[Score 1],0)
```

On test:

[image: FER]

UPDATE:

```
P_score = 
IF(
    [Score 1] = "Yes",1,
    IF(
        [Score 1] = "Fail",0.98,
    'Input - PI Scoring'[Score 2]/'Input - PI Scoring'[Score 1]))
```

[image: DERELI]

Note: Do not forget to format the P_score AS Percentage!

Comment: thanks, if i want to capture Yes as 100% and fail as lets say 98% how i can achieve that

Comment: Hello, I updated your request on my answer above! you can check it!

Comment: You're welcome! Stay Safe!

Comment: got this error with above query Error text The Result of a conversion or arithmetic operation is either too large or too small

Comment: Please check the data types of the column in Power Query Editor. If It can't work, then please put the screenshot of the problem into your post? It worked in my file without any problem!